# Copy Paste Entire Row only copying first instance

Tags: excel, vba

I have this program to copy an entire row to another sheet within the same workbook depending on if the person's name (pulled from let's say Sheet 1) is found to be on another spreadsheet (sheet 2).

The department is then used (From sheet 1) to place the name that is found on sheet 2 on the department specific sheet.

It is only printing the first instance of the condition and nothing else on every department page.

Main:

```vb
Sub copy2Sheets()
    Dim table As Worksheet: Set table = Worksheets("Table")
    Dim N As Long
    N = 117
    Dim i As Long
    Dim tempDep As String
    Dim tempName As String
    
    tempDep = table.Cells(1, "B").value
    tempName = table.Cells(1, "A").value
    copyPaste tempName, Worksheets(Trim(tempDep))
    'Loop Case:
    For i = 2 To N - 1
        tempDep = table.Cells(i, "B").value
        tempName = table.Cells(i, "A").value
        copyPaste tempName, Worksheets(Trim(tempDep))
    Next i
End Sub
```

PasteFunction:

```vb
Sub copyPaste(Name As String, place As Worksheet)
    'Worksheet Variables
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim targSource As Worksheet: Set targSource = place
    'CurrentLast Row As Long
    Dim iTargetRow As Long
    'Which Cell was Found
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim copyTo As Long: copyTo = targSource.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Assign Variables
    Set wsSource = Worksheets("Last Month's BBS SafeUnsafe by ")
    
    Set FoundCell = check(Name)
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        copyTo = copyTo + 1
        wsSource.Cells(FoundCell.Row).EntireRow.Copy targSource.Range("A" & copyTo)
    End If
End Sub
```

Check function:

```vb
Public Function check(Name As String) As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Last Month's BBS SafeUnsafe by ")
    If Trim(Name) <> "" Then
        Set Rng = ws.Range("C:C").Find(Name)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Set check = Rng
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Example Excel Sheets:

"Sheet 1"
[image]

Sheet 2
[image]

In the images, only the first entry from sheet 2 is being copied into every sheet, rather than every entry being pasted into their respective sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting up your code like that makes it more difficult to follow - try only using one method:

```vb
Sub copy2Sheets()
    Const N As Long = 116 'use const for fixed values
    
    Dim wsTable As Worksheet, wsBBS As Worksheet, i As Long
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet, f As Range, tempDep As String, tempName As String
    
    Set wsTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table")
    Set wsBBS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Last Month's BBS SafeUnsafe by ")
    
    For i = 1 To N
        tempDep = Trim(wsTable.Cells(i, "B").Value)
        tempName = Trim(wsTable.Cells(i, "A").Value)
        If Len(tempName) > 0 Then
            Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tempDep)
            Set f = wsBBS.Columns("C").Find(what:=tempName, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                 f.EntireRow.Copy wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```